# How can I create a 'Pulse' like UI for an android application

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I would like to know how can I create a Pulse like app on android
Here is a screenshot:
[image: http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/11/17/top-android-app-pulse-news-reader/]

A number of things:

1. It has a number of 'row's of horizontal content.
2. Each 'row' has 'cell's of content.
3. I can 'fling' left and right to see the horizontal content.
4. As it reaches the end of the horizontal content, it will automatically load more content.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually this is just a [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) containing a bunch of [`Gallery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) layouts using an infinite scrolling adapter like [`cwac-endless`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless). I think with a bit of work you can probably get them all to play nicely together.

Answer (score 1):

I just throw some quick and dirty example:

Here is your xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:text="News One" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TextView android:text="News Two" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView21"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView22"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView23"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView24"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView25"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView26"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image"></ImageView>
            <ImageView android:src="@drawable/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView27"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

To make it perfect, you can add border to each image, etc,etc.
But, you should get the idea from this layout.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use like a horizontal scrolling view with a custom layout for each element and then like load what you want in there? I dont really know just brainstorming. Sounds like it would work with that type of layout.